# Moving mass in two dimensions holded by 4 springs

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring

I want to study the behavior of the following system:

[image: schematic]

It is a 2D mass with that is connected at two points $(P_1, P_2)$ with for springs $(k_{x,1},k_{x,2},k_{y,1},k_{y,2})$ the Center of gravity is at point $S$. At first I want to look what will happen if a static force acts on the system and later how it will move. I was already able to figure out how the system will work without the $x$ components and the applied force, but including them brings me trouble. For me understanding how I can get to the system of differential equations would very helpful. Making assumptions to solve them will be a second step.

Comment: Show us what you did so far.

Comment: As I don't have much time left today here a short version. A more detailed one I can provide tomorrow:

At first I had a look without the additional y springs. I started with equilibrium of forces and torques:
-k1x*x1-k2x*x2=m*x''[t] and k1x*s1-k2x*s2*x2=J*phi''[t]

I came to the following differential equations:
J*m*s2^2)*x1''[t] - (J - m*s1*s2) x2''[t] + (s1 + s2)^2*k1*x1[t] == 0

and

-(J - m*s1*s2) x1''[t] + (J + m*s1^2) x2''[t] + (s1 + s2)^2*k2* x2[t] == 0

But I struggle getting a suitable approach that includes the additional spring and the force ...